# Windows 7 can't find driver for hpdeskjet 6112 series

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-printer

I have a hp deskjet 6112 connected to a windows xp box in another room. I can see it in the network on my windows 7 box but when I try and add it I get a message says that it can't find a driver and requests I browse for the INF file (the driver). I can't find a download for the actual driver anywhere (for vista 64 bit or windows 7 64 bit). What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the alternate driver supplied with Windows Vista, see [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00808478&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=83027&lang=en) for details. I also think you're referring to the 6122 series, as HP has no information on a 6112 series anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Like a lot of networked HP Printers, they haven't started releasing Win7 drivers just yet. I've got the same issue with a different model, and the Vista drivers have been sufficient for 99% of what I need out of the printer. Some of the extras are missing or buggy, but printing/scanning works fine.